# Can I connect various LED fixtures to one driver?

Tags: led, driver, dali

Let's say my driver is 32W (700mA). I should be easily able to connect 5 x 5W 350/700mA LEDs right?

My idea is to use driver with DALI interface and control 5 LED's using just one address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible, but you won't be able to control each of the LED but just all of the connected ones at once.

When connecting multiple LEDs to one driver make sure to understand the limits of the driver and the way it works. The rated wattage of the driver must be higher than the sum of the wattage of the LEDs (like you figured out, 32W driver > 25W LEDs). There may be a limit on the voltage as well, so some driver will be able to put out say 700mA for a voltage range of 24V-45V, so the permittable wattage range is 16.8W to 32W. In that case you have to add the forward voltages of your LEDs and check that it is in the range of the driver.

If you have a constant current controller you must connect the LEDs in series and each of the LED must be rated for the said constant current. Don't parallel two 350mA LEDs to get a virtual 700mA LED. (the current might not be evenly shared and that might damage the LED in the long run)

If your driver is constant voltage output (that makes it not really a LED driver but just a voltage source imho) you have to parallel the LEDs with a current limiter in series for each LED (don't use a single resistor to limit the total current).